# preg_replace_callback is not working on server

Tags: php, nginx

`preg_replace_callback();` is not working on NGINX server but it's working on local Apache server.

And i think is not a error of Apache/NGINX,

I am converting all emails from string to image but its showing some error as below.

```
Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, 'encode_email', to be a valid callback in /home/abc/public_html/test.php on line 170
```

you can see my code is here:

```
<?php
$email_pattern = '/[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/';
$text = 'my email is example@example.com and my second is example1@example.com';
$html = preg_replace_callback($email_pattern, "encode_email", "$text");

echo $html;

function encode_email($matches){
    return '<img src="image.php?id='. base64_encode($matches[0]) .'">';
}
?>
```

Comment: This is highly unlikely to be related to the nginx / apache difference. Could it be a difference between the PHP versions on the two systems?

Comment: @Simba You could be right, but both server have same php version but i think this is some logical or syntax error

Comment: You sure you don't want to use `preg_replace()`?!

Comment: i can use if any one have similar solution for it

Comment: If this is indeed the use-case then do `$callback = function () { /* encode email function body */ }` and then `$html = preg_replace_callback($email_pattern, $callback, "$text");` and check if it works.

Comment: You could also use an inline function in argument 2 rather than the name of a function defined elsewhere. If the function is only going to be used in this one place, that would make sense.
`$html = preg_replace_callback($email_pattern, function($m) { return ....... }, $text);`

Comment: issue has been solved with the help of http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make some changes as below:

```
$text = 'my email is example@example.com and my second is example1@example.com';
$email_pattern = '/[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/';
$html = preg_replace_callback($email_pattern, function ($matches){
    return '<img src="image.php?id='. base64_encode($matches[0]) .'">';
}, $text );
echo $html;
```

I hope it will work.